# Showing a Div when it has been reached - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, show, fade

I have a div quite a far part down the page. I want the div to appear when its been reached by scrolling. When the div is reached (about 30% through the div) is there a way I can have it fade it in?

I do hope that makes sense :s

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Yes, on scroll, check the scrollTop. if it's greater than x, show the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Though there are also numerous generic scrollspy plugins you could try. (But the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) one didn't work for me, so I made this.)

```
function scrollfadein(selector, offset, speed)
{
    if (speed == undefined)
    {
        speed = 1500;
    }

    $(selector)

    /* hide elements initially */
    .css('opacity', 0)

    /* each element gets its own callback so it can be removed after it's triggered */
    .each(function(){ 
        var el = $(this);
        var fun = function()
        {
            /* calculate offset if it's a fraction multiply by element height */
            offset = (offset == undefined) ? 0 : (offset < 1 ? offset*el.height() : offset);

            /* height and offset might all change if window is resized, so 
               always use up-todate values. */
            if ( $(window).scrollTop() > el.offset().top - $(window).height() + offset )
            {
                /* fadein element */
                el.animate({'opacity':1}, speed);

                /* remove callback now that it has triggered */
                $(window).off('scroll', fun);
            }
        };
        $(window).on('scroll', fun);
    });
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/eg4HS/